# Python: Injecting HTML content into a tag using `lxml.html`

Tags: python, html, parsing, lxml

I'm using the `lxml.html` library to parse an HTML document.

I located a specific tag, that I call `content_tag`, and I want to change its content (i.e. the text between `<div>` and `</div>`,) and the new content is a string with some html in it, say it's `'Hello <b>world!</b>'`.

How do I do that? I tried `content_tag.text = 'Hello <b>world!</b>'` but then it escapes all the html tags, replacing `<` with `&lt;` etc.

I want to inject the text *without* escaping any HTML. How can I do that?

Comment: The _nice_ way, since you are really trying to modify the DOM structure, would be to add a new child node for `world`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is one way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.6
from lxml.html import fromstring, tostring
from lxml.html import builder as E
fragment = """\
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">This is div.</div>
</div>"""

div = fromstring(fragment)
print tostring(div)
# <div id="outer">
#   <div id="inner">This is div.</div>
# </div>
div.replace(div.get_element_by_id('inner'), E.DIV('Hello ', E.B('world!')))
print tostring(div)
# <div id="outer">
#   <div>Hello <b>world!</b></div></div>
```

See also: http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#creating-html-with-the-e-factory

**Edit:** So, I should have confessed earlier that I'm not all that familiar with lxml. I looked at the docs and source briefly, but didn't find a clean solution. Perhaps, someone more familiar will stop by and set us both straight.

In the meantime, this seems to work, but is not well tested:

```
import lxml.html
content_tag = lxml.html.fromstring('<div>Goodbye.</div>')
content_tag.text = '' # assumes only text to start
for elem in lxml.html.fragments_fromstring('Hello <b>world!</b>'):
    if type(elem) == str: #but, only the first?
        content_tag.text += elem
    else:
        content_tag.append(elem)
print lxml.html.tostring(content_tag)
```

**Edit again:** and this version removes text and children

```
somehtml = 'Hello <b>world!</b>'
# purge element contents
content_tag.text = ''
for child in content_tag.getchildren():
    content_tag.remove(child)

fragments = lxml.html.fragments_fromstring(somehtml)
if type(fragments[0]) == str:
    content_tag.text = fragments.pop(0)
content_tag.extend(fragments)
```

Comment: That way doesn't work for me for 2 reasons: (1) I don't want to replace a tag, I want to replace the content of a tag and (2) The html segment that I want to inject is already in text form, I don't want to be building it with `E`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming content_tag doesn't have any subelement, you can just do:

```
from lxml import html
from lxml.html.builder import B

...

content_tag.text = 'Hello '
content_tag.append(B('world!'))
print html.tostring(content_tag)
```

Comment: Doesn't help-- My HTML text is not known beforehand and I can't construct it as an HTML structure in the code.

Comment: Ahh, but you didn't specify that in your question (the "is not known beforehand" part).

Comment: mwalsh's edited answer looks good and should work for arbitrary html.

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering around, i found this solution:

```
fragments = lxml.html.fragments_fromstring(<string with tags to inject>)
last = None

for frag in fragments:
  if isinstance(frag, lxml.etree._Element):
    content_tag.append(frag)
    last = frag
  else:
    if last:
      last.tail = frag
    else:
      content_tag.text = frag
```