# convert list to xml string in python

Tags: python

I have following list in Python:

```
list = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
```

and would like to convert it to following string:

```
<field>one</field><field>two</field><field>three</field><field>four/field><field>five</field>
```

what is the most efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be:

```
"".join("<field>{}</field>".format(x) for x in list)
```

This uses a "list comprehension" to iterate through your list and apply a string format to each element. Then, the elements created that way are joined together into one big string to get the final result.

Comment: thanks but instead '>' and '<' I am getting &lt; and &gt;

Comment: @bogumbiker: Well then there's more to what you're doing that you haven't shown. If you try the above interactively in a Python prompt, then it will produce the result you wanted. You are probably doing something like running this in a framework that automatically escapes HTML for you. If you want to generate raw HTML, you'll have to find a way to bypass that.

Comment: thanks for the hint. I am doing this inside lxml.builder perhaps that is why?

Comment: @bogumbiker: Yes, that's probably why. If you don't know how to solve that, then see [Python: Injecting HTML content into a tag using `lxml.html`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030987/python-injecting-html-content-into-a-tag-using-lxml-html)

Comment: it is a xml document and I am trying to do following:
 fields = "".join("<field>{}</field>".format(x) for x in list)
 doc = etree.fromstring(fields) but getting error

lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Extra content at the end of the document, line 1, column 20

Comment: and when I try to do the same with doc = html.fromstring(fields) it works but then somehow all elements are enclosed with <span> tag eg. <span>....my tags from the fields ...</span>

Comment: I'm struggling with a similar problem. has anyone found the solution yet? Please feel free to answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64004489/insert-list-of-elements-in-loop-inside-element-builder-in-lxml