# insert list of elements in loop inside element builder in lxml

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, list, lxml

I have a XML body which was constructed using `lxml.etree.E` module. It looks like this -

```
E.TAGA(
    E.TAGB(
        E.TAGC(
            ...list goes here...
        )
    )
)
```

This method of construction cannot be altered.

I have a list of strings `["textA", "textB", "textC"]` which have to be added to the xml under `TAGC` (as shown above) with each entry wrapped inside another tag `TAGD`. I have tried using `fromStringlist` but it doesn't work. Please help. Hope my question is clear.

This is how the final XML code should appear -

```
E.TAGA(
    E.TAGB(
        E.TAGC(
            E.TAGD(textA),
            E.TAGD(textB),
            E.TAGD(textC)
        )
    )
)
```

Here is the desired output -

```
<TAGA>
    <TAGB>
        <TAGC>
            <TAGD>textA</TAGD>
            <TAGD>textB</TAGD>
            <TAGD>textC</TAGD>
        </TAGC>
    </TAGB>
</TAGA>
```

Comment: Can you show us the actual wanted output? "Final XML" is not XML.

Comment: what is the expected XML result ?

Comment: I've updated my question. Please have a look.

Comment: You mention a list of strings. What does that look like? Please provide a [mcve],

Comment: updated the question. please see. :)

Comment: I don't think the E-factory syntax allows for loops when adding elements.

Answer (score 2):

Use the * operator for unpacking a list inside a function call...

That is, generate a list containing your

```
E.TAGD(textA),
E.TAGD(textB),
E.TAGD(textC)
```

then supply the list prefixed with * (the unpack operator) as an arg to E.TAGC

Answer (score -1):

below (using core python XML lib)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

d_data = ['T1', 'T2', 'T3']

a = ET.Element('A')
b = ET.SubElement(a, 'B')
c = ET.SubElement(b, 'C')
for text in d_data:
    temp = ET.SubElement(c, 'D')
    temp.text = text
ET.dump(a)
```

output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A>
   <B>
      <C>
         <D>T1</D>
         <D>T2</D>
         <D>T3</D>
      </C>
   </B>
</A>
```

Comment: I have mentioned that the XML is contructed using lxml. It's a part of the API and cannot be replaced. Moreoever, the method of construction of XML also cannot be changed.